# Create a Macro that inserts new data below last entry?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to the VBA and Macro world. I am trying to create a data collection sheet. First part data is collected in from 1 workbook and placed in workbook master. What I would like to achieve is the new data that I extract will be placed below the previous entry in the workbook master.

```
Sub Extract() ' ' Extract Macro ' ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e '
    Sheets("For Coordinator Use").Select
    Range("A2:M41").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Nimble Schedule Import Template- ops.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=0", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
    Windows("Coverage Request Form (9).xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Request Form").Select 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you would like to do it. Do you want to maybe use an array to store the data in then extract to the master spreadsheet or do you want to just use excels built in functions to copy and paste the data like you are doing above. You could also use a scripting dictionary to store the data as well there are many ways to do it just wondering which route you want to take. If you want to have a high performance macro then I suggest not to use excel's built in functions as they are slower than using arrays.

Update 2015-08-20
I have got the copy and paste using the range object. However I see you want to delete some other values from your list although they are kept in a table and not in a spreadsheet. Is this correct? Please have a look at the code I made some comments asking for some clarifications. Sorry for taking so long I was busy finishing something up at work.

```
Sub Extract() ' ' Extract Macro ' ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e '

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
Set wb = ThisWorkbook    'Set up the Excel objects you want to use
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("For Coordinator Use")
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:M41") 'asuming this is not changing
'Sheets("For Coordinator Use").Select 'You do not need to select if you use the objects
'Range("A2:M41").Select 'You do not need to select if you use the objects
'Selection.Copy 'you can also get rid of this if using objects
Dim wbDest As Workbook, wsDest As Worksheet, rngDest As Range
Set wbDest = Application.Workbooks("Nimble Schedule Import Template- ops.xlsx") ' Assuming that it is opened
'Windows("Nimble Schedule Import Template- ops.xlsx").Activate 'dont need to activate anything
Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rngDest = wsDest.Range("A1:A35000")

''optimize the application
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
''''
'''Find the first empty cell in destRng
'Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Select ' this will select the range that is blank only if it does not have data to begin with
Dim i As Long, j As Long, rngAdd As String 'i is the counter and j stores the row where it is blank
For i = 1 To rngDest.Cells.Count
    If IsEmpty(rngDest.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
        j = i
        i = rngDest.Cells.Count
    End If
Next i

'reset the rngDest
Set rngDest = Nothing
rngAdd = "A" & j & ":M" & (j + 39)
Set rngDest = wsDest.Range(rngAdd)

'make rngDest = rng.Value since they have the same dimension this works
rngDest = rng.Value 'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
'    :=False, Transpose:=False
'I am not sure what you are trying to acheive here a filter??'ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
'    "=0", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
'Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Selection.EntireRow.Delete
'ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
''Looks like you are deleting all with a value of "=0"
'Windows("Coverage Request Form (9).xlsx").Activate
'Sheets("Request Form").Select

'Release Objects
Set rngDest = Nothing
Set wsDest = Nothing
Set wbDest = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing

''set excel optimization as normal again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAuto
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what an array is.  I recorded this macro so that's why you see the copy and paste functions.  I'm open to suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified and commented copy of your code:

```
Sub Extract() ' ' Extract Macro ' ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e '
    Sheets("For Coordinator Use").Select
    Range("A2:M41").Copy 'No need to select then copy, just copy is fine
    Windows("Nimble Schedule Import Template- ops.xlsx").Activate
    'I have offset the last row of data by 1 row below, use rows.count rather than a hard row number. Also no need to select
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=0", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
    'I don't know what row is selected here but it was in your code so I left it, also no need for cutcopymode as it will cancel when you delete anyway
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
    Windows("Coverage Request Form (9).xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Request Form").Select
End Sub
```

Please read the comments and ask any questions about it where you are unsure. These changes are because you have stipulated you are new to this and I don't want to confuse you, this is NOT the best way to do it, I would much rather set up something with arrays than a copy and paste. If you are comfortable with this concept post back and I will modify my code for you.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the help!  The code you provided seems to work.  However, when the data in the master workbook is deleted (it's more of a template which needs to be used every day) the macro will still paste the data on the row below where the old data USED to be, as opposed to the top of the sheet again.
Also, I'm very open to the idea of making this macro more efficient, I just want to make sure it's something I can understand and explain to my coworkers.  Thanks again!

Comment: Also, an I'm not sure how relevant this is, but I created this macro by recording it.  I'm not familiar enough with VBA yet to write it.  That being said, I'm very open to streamlining it and making it more efficient.

Comment: I'm a little confused, so you want to paste then delete everything above it?

Comment: I paste a selection that includes invalid entries ("#N/A" or "0")  So I paste everything and then remove the invalid entries.  If there is a simpler way to do this (and I'm sure there is) I'm very open to suggestions. Hope that cleared it up!